# Java Inheritance Example from Building Java Programs Help - Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a quick question regarding inheritance.  Following along an inheritance example from the book *Building Java Programs* (Second Edition), I keep getting the same error that my subclass, *Secretary*, is not being found (Cannot find symbol error).

Below is the class code.

```
//A class to represent employees in general

public class Employee {
  public int getHours() {
    return 40;
  }

  public double getSalary() {
    return 40000.0;
  }

  public int getVacationDays() {
    return 10;
  }

  public String getVacationForm() {
    return "yellow";
  }  

  //A subclass, Secretary, inherits all of the superclass, Employee, 
  fields/states

  public class Secretary extends Employee {
    public void takeDictation(String text) {
      System.out.println("Dictating text: " + text);
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the client code.

```
//client code for Employee

public class EmployeeMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Employee: ");
    Employee edna = new Employee();
    System.out.print(edna.getHours() + ", ");
    System.out.printf("$.2f, ", edna.getSalary());
    System.out.print(edna.getVacationDays() + ", ");
    System.out.println(edna.getVacationForm());

    System.out.print("Secretary: ");
    Secretary stan = new Secretary();    //This is where I get the error
    System.out.print(stan.getHours() + ", ");
    System.out.printf("$.2f, ", stan.getSalary());
    System.out.print(stan.getVacationDays() + ", ");
    System.out.println(stan.getVacationForm());
    stan.takeDictation("hello world");
  }
}
```

I followed everything from the book yet I don't understand how I'm getting the error. Everything is in the same file.  The constructor *Employee* works fine just *Secretary* does not.   I appreciate any help.

Comment: the definition of the class Secretary should be in its own file named Secretary.java - in the above code it is a class defined inside Employee (an inner class)

Comment: Thank you so much! The book did not mention this at all, it had the subclass inside the employee class in the code provided!  It is working correctly as intended thank you again!

Comment: just to complete, inner classes are a valid design, but not in that case, and to instanciate one you need an instance of the 'outer' class first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `Secretary` class into it's own file named `Secretary.java`.

The issue arises since your Secretary class is within your Employee class (the Secretary class is then called an "inner class"). You could alternatively fix this problem by using the enclosing instance new operator which requires an instance of the outer class (in your case Employee) to create the inner class (Secretary). In your case, it would look like this: `Secretary stan = edna.new Secretary();`

However, you should do the first suggestion of putting the Secretary class in its own file.

Comment: does it make sense that Secretary is a inner class? (despite fixing the problem)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger No, especially in this inheritance example. One should reserve inner classes for more specific situations like hiding the class from other implementations. For example a Node in a LinkedList shouldn't be exposed, instead we hide the Node implementation within a LinkedList class and instead only expose the value the Node holds in the LinkedList.

Comment: Additionally, inner classes have access to all the variables of the outer class (including the private ones!), so in general unless there is a very special relationship between the inner and outer class, you don't create inner classes. So in this inheritance example, it doesn't make since to be both an inner class and a subclass of Employee. Secretrary definitely belongs in its own class.

Answer (score 0):

When you use inheritance especially in java you want to use different classes.

Dont try to include one class into another.

e.g.

```
class name1 {
   //do code
}



 class name2 extends name1 {
       //do code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following [MrWayFarOut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732003/mrwayfarout)'s answer and moving the Secretary class to a separate file. But if you really want to keep Secretary inside of Employee, you can do it like this:

- Change Secretary to be static:

  ```
  public static class Secretary extends Employee {
  ```
- When instantiating the Secretary object, use Employee.Secretary:

  ```
  Employee.Secretary stan = new Employee.Secretary();
  ```